# How convert any record into a map/dictionary in F#?

Tags: dictionary, f#, converters, record

I need to serialize arbitrary records into maps/dictionary.

I imagine my end type look like this:

```
type TabularData= array<Map<string, obj>>
```

But I have problems in build a generic function that accept *any record* and turn them into Map.

Comment: you should take a look at [FSharpType.GetRecordFields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353417.aspx) or [FSharpValue.GetRecordFields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370527.aspx)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In practice, the best advice is probably to use some existing serialization library like [FsPickler](http://nessos.github.io/FsPickler/). However, if you really want to write your own serialization for records, then `GetRecordFields` (as mentioned in the comments) is the way to go.

The following takes a record and creates a map from `string` field names to `obj` values of the fields. Note that it does not handle nested records and it is not particularly fast:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

let asMap (recd:'T) = 
  [ for p in FSharpType.GetRecordFields(typeof<'T>) ->
      p.Name, p.GetValue(recd) ]
  |> Map.ofSeq
```

Here is a little example that calls this with a simple record:

```
type Person =
  { Name : string 
    Age : int }

asMap { Name = "Tomas"; Age = -1 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the same idea mentioned by Tomas, you can create a `IDictionary<K,V>` from a record like this:

```
let asDictionary (entity: 'T) =
    seq {
        for prop in FSharpType.GetRecordFields(typeof<'T>) -> 
        prop.Name, prop.GetValue(entity)
    } |> dict
```